# How to: aligned multiline equations

Tags: equations, align, alignment

Two of these equations do not fit the column of the two-column layout.

[image]

They are coded with `\align` such that they all align at the `=` following the scheme

```
\begin{align}
...
\dot\omega &= ...
\dot f &=
...
\end{align}
```

Now I can of course brute force make a line break as in

```
\begin{align}
...
\dot\omega &= ... \notag \\
&- ...
\dot f &= ... \notag \\
&+ ...
...
\end{align}
```

which yields

[image]

However I do not find that ideal. It would look much better if the second line of each multi-line equation was rather aligned to the right.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please, provide code for shoved equation in form of small, complete and compilable document that we not need to retype equations.

Comment: Take a look at `multlined` from `mathtools`.  That will allow you to divide just part of a long equation.  You will also need to use `\biggl` (or the appropriate size) instead of `\left`, etc.  (This is the best I can do without knowing what document class and other code you are using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than pushing the second line of a two-line equation to the far right, you appear to consider only one other alignment possibility, *viz.*, to place the first item on the second line smack dab below the `=` symbol in the first line; see equation (A.5') in the following screenshot.

I'd like to point out that there are at least two additional alignment possibilities: (a) pushing the second line to the right by `\quad`, and (b) pushing the second line to the right by `\qquad`. These two possibilities are illustrated by equations (A.5'') and (A.5''') in the following screenshot. The final equation, labelled (A.5''''), is generated with the help of a `multlined` environment, a possibility already mentioned in a comment provided by @barabarabeeton.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I can't see anything wrong with the fixed indentation amounts of `\quad` and `\qquad` shown in equations (A.5'') and (A.5'''). There's nothing wrong with equation (A.5'''') either. However, achieving that look involves considerably more setting-up overhead than either (A.5'') or (A.5''') do. For sure, the look of (A.5') isn't as good as that of either of the following three equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% trying to replicate the look of the OP's screenshots:
\usepackage[letterpaper,twocolumn,margin=0.667in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\renewcommand\theequation{A.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\addtocounter{equation}{3}
\dot{\Omega} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{ 1+e\cos f}\frac{1}{\sin\imath}\mathcal{W}\\
%% no linebreak
\dot{\omega} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{1}{e}\biggl(-\cos f\mathcal{R} + \frac{2+e\cos f}{1+e\cos f}\sin f\mathcal{S} -e\cot\imath \frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{1+e\cos(f)} \mathcal{W}\biggr) \label{a5}\\
%% 1 linebreak, no indentation
\dot{\omega} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{1}{e}\biggl(-\cos f\mathcal{R} + \frac{2+e\cos f}{1+e\cos f}\sin f\mathcal{S} \tag{\ref{a5}$'$} \\
&-e\cot\imath \frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{1+e\cos(f)} \mathcal{W}\biggr) \notag\\
%% \quad indentation
\dot{\omega} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{1}{e}\biggl(-\cos f\mathcal{R} + \frac{2+e\cos f}{1+e\cos f}\sin f\mathcal{S} \tag{\ref{a5}$''$} \\
&\quad-e\cot\imath \frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{1+e\cos(f)} \mathcal{W}\biggr) \notag \\
%% \qquad indentation
\dot{\omega} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{1}{e}\biggl(-\cos f\mathcal{R} + \frac{2+e\cos f}{1+e\cos f}\sin f\mathcal{S} \tag{\ref{a5}$'''$} \\
&\qquad-e\cot\imath \frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{1+e\cos(f)} \mathcal{W}\biggr) \notag \\
%% multlined solution
\dot{\omega} 
&= \begin{multlined}[t]
\sqrt{\frac{p}{Gm}}\frac{1}{e}\biggl(-\cos f\mathcal{R} + \frac{2+e\cos f}{1+e\cos f}\sin f\mathcal{S} \tag{\ref{a5}$''''$} \\
-e\cot\imath \frac{\sin(\omega+f)}{1+e\cos(f)} \mathcal{W}\biggr)
\end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great list of solutions. Thank you so much @Micro! I will try out each of them and see what looks best to me. Cheers!

Comment: It is indeed, sorry for that!